# Unable to find any Xcode installations thats supports at least iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium, ios-simulator, appcelerator

I haven't used my development tools for Appecelerator Titanium in a while (Studio and CLI). Now I try to run an existing app in the iOS simulator.

From studio I can not select the iOS simulators.
When I use the CLI and execute: appc run (platform iOS) i get this message:

Unable to find any Xcode installations thats supports at least iOS 8.0

I have Xcode version 9.0.1 installed. 
**How can i connect Xcode with Titanium again?**

The path of the active XCode developer directory (xcode-select -p) is:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Answer (score 2):

You're probably on an SDK older than 6.2. xcode 9 isn't supported by older SDK's for obvious reasons. You can either install xcode8 (downloadable from the apple website) or you can upgrade to Titanium SDK 6.2 or higher (6.3 came out, I recommend that)

For information regarding versioning (of everything related to Ti, check [the compatibility matrix in the documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix))

Comment: Hi Rene, thanks for your reply. I am on SDK 6.3, everything is up to date, that's the strange thing. When I start the simulators from xcode itself it works. I even de-installed all titanium stuff and re-installed it. Same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem today after installed Xcode 9.2, on side of Xcode 9.4.1 and Titanium SDK 7.2.0.GA. Same error message as in the title of this post. As suggested by Patrick De Marta, I've tried

```
appc run -p ios -T simulator -C x
```

after that, I could select a simulator and run the app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you execute "appc ti sdk list" from command line ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is your case, but I had a similar problem and solved it by specifying the target simulator with the CLI build option -C

(**appc ti info** for the list of simulator names )

hope this helps