# ERROR Unable to find any Xcode installations that supports iOS Simulator 13.2.2

Tags: xcode, titanium, titanium-sdk

I tried this two question [Question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62417189/unable-to-find-any-xcode-installations-that-supports-ios-simulator-13-2-2) and [Question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47098163/unable-to-find-any-xcode-installations-thats-supports-at-least-ios-8-0) nothing works for me. Tried reset sim also.

Below are log details:

`appc run -p ios -T simulator -C`

Output of this command :

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 8.0.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2020, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

[ERROR] Invalid iOS simulator "x"

 
6/30/2020, 2:36:20 PM

Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.14.6
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 12
  Memory                      = 17179869184

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 10.19.0
  npm Version                 = 6.13.4

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.2.2

Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 7.5.1.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.1.GA
  Target Platform             = iphone

Command
  /usr/local/bin/node /Users/UserName/.appcelerator/install/8.0.0/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js build -p ios -T simulator -C x --config-file /var/folders/qq/fc1mtjjs42v5nh0phrf346p00000gn/T/build-1593507977953.json --log-level info --no-banner --project-dir /Users/Username/Project/titanium

[ERROR] Unable to find any Xcode installations that supports iOS Simulator 13.2.2.
```

Whenever running `tn tn iphone-8-ios-13-3` or ios device command getting below error:

```
[ERROR] Invalid iOS simulator "FAA5DC77-27EC-4D74-8C5C-DFA77975DF80"
```

Output of `ti info`

```
Xcode
  11.3.1 (build 11C504) - Xcode default
    Install Location          = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    iOS SDKs                  = 13.2.2
    iOS Simulators            = 13.2.2
    Watch SDKs                = 6.1
    Watch Simulators          = 6.1
    Supported by TiSDK 7.5.1.GA = yes
    EULA Accepted             = yes
    Teams                     = none
```

Note: I want to migrate app from 7.4.X to latest but before that i want to know what is causing issue apps to works from 7.5.x to latest version.

I tried this also https://github.com/appcelerator/ioslib/issues/115 no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is solved by following step :

1. `rm ioslib` inside `/Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.1.GA/node_modules/`
2. `npm install ioslib@1.7.14`
3. `tn reset` to regenerate devices

I got to know this by below error log :

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.1.GA/node_modules/titanium-sdk/package.json'

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path /Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.1.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.1.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp: is outside /Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.1.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/node_modules/node-pre-gyp and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: /Users/Username/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/7.5.1.GA/node_modules/node-ios-device/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Username/.npm/_logs/2020-06-30T09_42_55_036Z-debug.log
```

Comment: What's that 'tn reset' command ? I can't find any executable 'tn' nor any documentation about it

Comment: You can try ti reset